# D3: Transition between polygons

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/4395/) is a D3 project I am working on. It updates a shape of a regular polygon from n to either n-1 or n+1 angles. Pressing the buttons a,b,c,d or e will trigger this. I followed the tutorial on [general update patterns](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) and have tried to follow patterns in many other samples I have found, most notably bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153.

Here is the drawing function

```
function draw(data) {

var v = vis.selectAll("polygon")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d; });

// enter selection
v.enter().append("polygon");

// update selection
v.attr("class", "update")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("points",function(d) { 
    return d.map(function(d) { return [d.x,d.y].join(","); }).join(" ");})
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width",2);

// exit selection
v.exit().attr("class", "exit")
.transition()
  .duration(750).remove();
};
```

And the updating function

```
function update() {
if (this.classList.contains('on')) {
     d3.select(this).classed('on',false)
     letters.pop(this.id);
}
else {
     d3.select(this).classed('on',true)
     letters.push(this.id);
}
var N = letters.length;
draw([poly(N,N,[])]);
};
```

My question is how and where to call an interpolation to make this go smoothly from one polygon to the next?

Thanks

Comment: You already have a transition in there. Is that not working for you?

Comment: There is a transition yes. I hope you can see that on the fiddle. However I want it to move from one shape to the other and not have one appearing over the other one which then disappears.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, missed the fiddle link. [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153) should help.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I had actually put this example also as a link in my question. I may be thinking my code wrong completely but as for now the fundamental difference in mine and this one is that he writes his own interpolation while I should be able to use d3.interpolation(newPolygon,oldPolygon). What I can´t figure out is where to put it. Thanks again for looking at this.

Comment: Argh, I promise to read more carefully next time! The main thing about this example is that it's not using a `polygon`, but a `path` element with the `d` attribute set correctly (this should be easy in your case as well). Then the transition should work without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Lars for looking over my question. I had figured this much but I didn't know where this would come in. I think the problem was that I was creating new polygons instead of changing the old ones (which is what happens in the updating example, old out and new in). Most people link to the California-> circle example but [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1020902) actually helped much more with less code.

By combining what I had before with this example I got [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/4401/). The update function now being

```
function update() {
 if (this.classList.contains('on')) {
     d3.select(this).classed('on',false)
     letters.pop(this.id);
}
else {
     d3.select(this).classed('on',true)
     letters.push(this.id);
}
var N = letters.length;
d3.select(".big").transition().duration(500).attr("points", mapPoints(poly(N,N,[])));};
```

There are obviously still many faults with this but I am happy with the animations.